# Where did the three-dimensional axes' orientation convention come from?

Tags: math-history, convention

When one thinks of the axes for two-dimensional space, one envisions two axes that are perpendicular to each other. The $x$ axis increases horizontally from left to right, and the $y$ axis is vertical and increases from down to up. This has the advantage of being a convention which is usually followed, although in some software such as game-making software, I noticed that the $y$ axis increases from top to bottom.

When I learned about the three-demensional space axes, I assumed intuitively that the $z$ axis would be a natural extension of the axes of two-dimensional space -- that is, the $z$ axis would be perpendicular to the $x$ and $y$ axes -- horizontal, increasing from where it is close to you to where it goes far away from you. However, I learned that that wasn't the case. The axes seem to be orientated much differently.

Where did the currently accepted convention originate from, and why isn't it more similar to the two-dimensional space axes?

Comment: The standard, right-handed coordinate system _is_ similar to the two-dimensional one. If you draw your regular $x$ and $y$ axes on a piece of paper lying flat on a table, the $z$-axis comes _out_ of the paper, and increases as it goes upwards. In the end, however, there is no objective reason to favour one over the other, so the conventions aren't entirely set in stone.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason the $x$ and $y$ axes aren't depicted as being horizontal and vertical though, even if the relative orientations are similar? It seems to be a convention which may not be as strictly held as the two-dimensional space convention, though.

Comment: You're right that it isn't as strictly held. For instance, I have dabbled in the game making engine Unity, where the coordinates are as you describe them, with $x$ increasing to the right, $y$ increasing upwards and $z$ increasing away from me. It has caused some headaches as I am so used to working in right-handed systems.